# Bootstrap Vue editable table column

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have a table with one of the columns storing an input

```
  <b-table bordered stripped
                         show-empty
                         empty-text="Your cart is empty"
                         class="p-2"
                         :fields="fields"
                         :items="lines">
                    <template slot="quantity" slot-scope="line">
                        <input type="number" class="form-control-sm"
                               style="width:5em"
                               v-model="qvalue"
                               v-on:input="handleQuantityChange($event,line.item)"/>
                    </template>
                    <template slot="product" slot-scope="line">
                        {{line.item.product.name}}
                    </template>
                    <template slot="price" slot-scope="line">
                        {{ line.item.product.price| currency }}
                    </template>
                    <template slot="subtotal" slot-scope="line">
                        {{ (line.item.quantity*line.item.product.price) | currency }}
                    </template>
                    <template slot="remove" slot-scope="line">
                        <b-button size="sm" variant="danger" v-on:click="handleRemove(line)">
                            Remove
                        </b-button>
                    </template>
                </b-table>
```

The problem is with first column and qvalue binding, when I add more than one values: I have the same value in two rows. How can I have two different values?  Methods are below:

```
 methods:{
            ...mapMutations({
                change:"cart/changeQuantity",
                remove: "cart/removeProduct"
            }),
            handleQuantityChange(e,line){
                if (e.target.value >0){
                    this.qvalue = e.target.value;
                } else {
                    this.qvalue = 1;
                    e.target.value = this.qvalue
                }
                this.change({line,quantity:e.target.value})
            },


            handleRemove(line){
                this.remove(line.item);
            }

        }
```

I ubderstand that v-modelling qvalue is not good, but what is a correct way?

Comment: Where do you declare `qvalue`? In Vue component or in Vuex? Please include that code.

Comment: In Vue component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `v-model` you could use `:value="line.item.quantity"`.

So your input would look like this:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control-sm"
                           style="width:5em"
                           :value="line.item.quantity"
                           v-on:input="handleQuantityChange($event,line.item)"/>
```

[Here](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/forms.html) is more information on form handling with vuex.